# Custom Ask page in Wordpress does not work

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using wordpress to create blog similar to **stackoverflow.com** where users can ask questions. I decided that since my Ask page is "same all the time" I create a new page called ask.php. This page will contain the FORM. The problem is that i cannot link that page correctly.

In the header template I give the link to my ask page. I believe this link links to custom php file in my themes folder **wp-content\themes\mythemename**

```
<a href="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/ask.php"> ask</a>
```

For the sake of simplicity the contents of my Ask (ask.php) page is just 'diplay one header', no loop no footer etc.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
```

The problem when i click on the **ask** link an empty page is opened. When i hover mouse over the link I can see the link is correct http://mysitename.com/wp-content/themes/own/index.php, where 'own' is my theme folder.

And this this a problem I created different php pages and changed the link accordingly but always an empty page is opened. Even when I try to give link to index.php

```
<a href="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/index.php"> Home</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you're ask.php theme file should contain the following lines at the top :

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Ask
*/
```

Then add a new page from wp-admin called Ask , and from the right sidebar on the edit page select the template `Ask` for this page . Everithing should work just fine .

p.s. don't include a link to the file in you're header but instead let wp list the page with the permalink you've set in wp-admin when you added the page .

Comment: Thanks, will try for now let me ask you a question then. Creating a page from admin means the page will be created as a record in db (but page not post). That means no file will be created. Can I just use static php file instead of dynamic page or it;s just not good?

Comment: It will be a bit harder to setup a static php file , using my example will act just the same but instead you don't have to mess with wordpress bootstrap/configs/whatever/permalinks/resources ...

Comment: You can do both but not at the same time . If you post the form in the page rather than the template you will have to call the wp query ( in you're template ) to show the content and you will have less "manipulation" of the form from php , tough it will be easyer to edit later on . I recomend for start to use the template just as you would do it with a plain php file and leave the page content empty from wp-admin just till you learn a bit more then you'll probably whant to refactor you're code based on the specs you're setting .

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as though you have created a page in a separate PHP file and not included the WordPress header. Without that, you cannot use WordPress functions like `get_bloginfo()`.

Consider including the header, or creating a static WordPress Page for your form.

Also, ensure that PHP errors are set to display on your server to help you through this process.

Comment: Ok i didn't included header in my ask.php. But index.php is working when I go to home. But its not opening from the link <a href="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/index.php"> Home</a>. That is the problem. I want to give link to file XXX.php located in my theme folder